# Page View Counter in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I'm wondering how you make a page view counter in Laravel 5. Is there any specific package that will help me out with this? I'm basically stuck, as the stable version of Laravel 5 was recently released.

Comment: I don't think laravel has something build in for this. This is a good example http://codebase.eu/source/code-php/ip-counter/.

Comment: there is no such feature in Laravel.

Answer (score 22):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but each way has its pros and cons. In this answer, I will describe two ways to build a pageview counter.

## #1 Simple column in a database table

Let's say we are building a blog with posts and we want to keep track of the total pageviews count. What we can do is adding the column `views` or `page_views` to our posts database table. This column will store the total number of page views. We can increment this number every time a post is being shown to someone.

Example code:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = \App\Models\Post::find($id); // fetch post from database
    $post->increment('views'); // add a new page view to our `views` column by incrementing it

    return view('posts.show', [
        'post' => $post,
    ]);
}
```

Then inside your view (blade or php), you can get the column like this;

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    Views: {{ $post->views }}
</div>
```

But in this way, we will never know when people exactly viewed the post. It will only possible to get the total count and not the total views of the past 24 hours, 7 days, 14 weeks or from "12-01-2017".

## #2 Extra table to store all views

This way is very different from way #1 because each page view will be stored as a record in the table.

Before writing the steps I want to tell you that I created a package called: [`Eloquent Viewable`](https://packagist.org/packages/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable). It works exactly like #2.

First you need to create a database migration for the `views` table. This migration should contain the following:

```
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
$table->morphs('viewable');
$table->timestamps();
```

Then we need to create an Eloquent model, so we can fetch the views:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class View extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'views';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

Then add to each model that can be viewed or needs this functionality the following code. In this example, we are providing this functionality to the `Post` model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the page views associated with the given model.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function views()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(
            \App\Models\View::class,
            'viewable'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the total number of views.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getViewsCount()
    {
        return $this->views()->count();
    }

    public function getViewsCountSince($sinceDateTime)
    {
        return $this->views()->where('created_at', '>', $sinceDateTime)->count();
    }

    public function getViewsCountUpto($uptoDateTime)
    {
        return $this->views()->where('created_at', '<', $uptoDateTime)->count();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the following methods to fetch the views counts.

```
// total number of views
$post->getViews();

// total number of views since the past 24 hours
$post->getViewsCountSince(Carbon::now()->subDay(1));

// total number of views upto 2 months ago
$post->getViewsCountUpto(Carbon::now()->subMonths(2));
```

Answer (score 4):

This package is awesome and easy to use, i was get the same issue but i found with this package the solving 
`Kryptonit3/Counter`

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to build this your self it would be quite easy.

Create a new middleware in `app/Htpp/Middleware/PageViews.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PageViews
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        PageView::increment();

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Now add `\App\Http\Middleware\PageViews::class` to the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class.

Obviously I put in PageView::increment() which won't work cause PageView is not implemented. The simplest way to implement for you would probably to create a table with an int for pageviews and create a PageView model.

A more advanced solution would be to store this in a cache and with a cron job save it to permanent storage once every hour. Just to limit the performance hit of saving page views.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package, it's very easy to use

https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable#recording-views

few things you can do once installed and configred:

```php
// Return total views count
views($post)->count();

// Return total views count that have been made since 20 February 2017
views($post)->period(Period::since('2017-02-20'))->count();

// Return total views count that have been made between 2014 and 216
views($post)->period(Period::create('2014', '2016'))->count();

// Return total unique views count (based on visitor cookie)
views($post)->unique()->count();

// Record a new view
views($post)->record();

// Record a new view with session delay between views
views($post)->delayInSession(now()->addHours(2))->record();
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)